# Intergrate 3rd party app for Cocos Creator games

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x, cocoscreator

I am new to Cocos Creator (and Cocos2dx, too). I'm planning to develop a game for iOS, Android and Web platform.

Is it possible to integrate these apps to game developed by Cocos Creator:

- Appflyers, Google Analytics, Firebase (for tracking user)
- In-app purchase (for Android and iOS)

Comment: Try asking in the cocos2d-x forums https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDKBOX may help you.
Intro: http://www.sdkbox.com

You can read this manual for integrating SDKs

http://docs.sdkbox.com/en/qa/integration-admob-to-creator/